# Error on variable $mysqli->result which I don't access at all yet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got this error:

**Catchable fatal error:** Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in **J:\xampp\htdocs\components\bo_testedit.php** on line 50

And this is on `bo_testedit.php` line 50:

```
ExecSQL (__FILE__, $mysqli, "DELETE FROM question_assign WHERE id_question = {$id}");
```

And this is on `functions_db.php`:

```
function ExecSQL ($scriptparent, $mysqli, $query) {
    $mysqli->query ($query);
    if ($mysqli->error != "") { DBErrorLogger ($scriptparent, $mysqli->error, $query); return $mysqli->error; }
    return true;
}
```

And this is also on `functions_db.php`:

```
function DBErrorLogger ($functionname, $error, $query = "") {
    $logmessage = "<br>Functions_db.php:\nFunction <strong>{$functionname}</strong> raised error:<br>\n{$error}";
    if ($query != "") $logmessage = $logmessage . "<br>\nwhile executing this query: \n<strong>{$query}</strong>";
    Logger ($logmessage);
}
```

From what I've learned from googling, this error occurs because I want to store object `$mysqli->result` into a string type variable. One thing that bothers me here, I didn't access `$mysqli->result` in all these codes. Why it returns such error message? I do access it in another lines on `bo_testedit.php`, but they're seems fine (returning correct result). Is it possible that the line number from this error was incorrect (i.e refer to another line)?

EDIT: Sorry for the long reply. The problem persist of several days despite of anything I did, but then the problem suddenly disappear despite I didn't do anything to it. I still don't know where the problem is, but I surely do hope it will never coming back again. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: What does `$mysqli->error` contain? Can you give a `var_dump();`?

Comment: seems like you could fix the error AND get better injection safety by using a prepared statement and parameter substitution, instead of string substitution.

Comment: One suggestion: instead of checking `if ($mysqli->error != "")` check the return value:
 `$result = $mysqli->query ($query);if ($result === false) `

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM question_assign WHERE id_question = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {   
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();    
    /*Count the rows*/
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
       echo 'It worked !';
    }else{
      var_dump($mysqli->error);
      die();
    }   
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}   
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: 1) you never bound the $id to the query's parameter, and 2) code-only answers don't really help much. This is completely different code than the OP's, and while many people could write that, it doesn't shed light on what was wrong with the OP code.

Comment: @RobP thanks for pointing this out, I have adjusted it , as for the explanation I think the comments are self explanatory. I am trying to help OP I dont think I deserve downvote for that, if anything you can always edit my answer